# No se muestra mi mensaje de connect-flash en pug

Tags: nodejs, express, pug

Quisiera saber si alguien podría ayudarme con un problema que tengo en mi aplicación de node js. Estoy usando Passport para manejar inicio de sesión, mediante Pug, con mensajes de error y éxito de connect-flash, parece ser que todo esta correcto, y según la documentación en Pug, la condicional la estoy poniendo de manera correcta, pero por alguna razón parece que ser que ignora el If e imprime directamente los mensajes al mismo tiempo. Muestro mi código de los mensajes en Pug:

```
if message
    .container
        .row 
            .col-md-4-mx-auto 
                .alert.alert-danger.alert-dismissible.fade.show(role="alert")
                    #{message} 
                    button(type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close")
                        span(aria-hidden="true") &times;
if success
    .container
        .row 
            .col-md-4-mx-auto 
                .alert.alert-success.alert-dismissible.fade.show(role="alert")
                    #{success} 
                    button(type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close")
                        span(aria-hidden="true") &times;
```

Este es mi codigo de Passport:

```
passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'usuario',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, usuario, password, done) =>{
    await usuarios.findOne({
        where: {
            usuario: usuario
        }
    }).then(function(usuario){
        if(usuario){
            if(usuario.password === password){
                done(null, usuario, req.flash('success', 'Bienvenido '+ usuario));
            }else{
                done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Usuario o Contraseña incorrectos'));
                console.log(req.flash('message'));
            }
        }else{
            console.log(req.flash('message'));
            return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Usuario o Contraseña incorrectos'));
        }
    })
}));
```

Y en el archivo principal tengo todo declarado bien:

```
// middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser('cpsSecret'));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'cpsSecret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(flash());

// Variables globales
app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    app.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    app.locals.message = req.flash('message');
    next();
});
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias.